# Update content link property of content editor webpart using CSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, csom, content-editor-web-part

I am trying to set the content link property of `content editor webpart` using CSOM using the code below

```
try
  {
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("_catalogs/wp/sample.dwp");
     ctx.Load(file, fe => fe.Exists);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     file.ListItemAllFields["ContentLink"] = siteUrl;
     file.ListItemAllFields.Update();
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
  }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
     throw;
  }
```

it throws an

> "Value does not fall within expected range"

exception on `ctx.executequery`